# Does C++11 or C++14 support "&& const" in declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Is the following definition (from a piece of C++ source code) valid?

```
struct Test_
{
    int i;
    Test_(int j) : i(j) { }
    int try() && { return i; }
    int try() && const { return -i; }
};
```

I mean if it's valid to put const after &&.
This code is about overload resolution with ref-qualifier.

I know const && is valid. I wonder if "&& const" is supported in C++11 or C++14.

Comment: Yes, this is allowed, though const rvalues are relatively hard to come by (e.g. `std::move` of a constant value).

Comment: Can I ask what it means ? With a quick search I could not find anything and my tests don't help me much.